# How do I add colored text or highlighting to txt files in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use vscode for writing notes for some reason... namely I can't use onenote or evernote. i don't have much coding experience... is it impossible to change the formatting of txt files, so that i can highlight or change to color of individual words inside vscode?

also, is it possible to start files with the outline [+] on the sidebar collapsed?

Comment: Please check stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try [TODO](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-todo-plus) files

Comment: You can hide `outline` by right clicking on it and unchecking

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.foreground": "#586e75"
},
```

The `editor.foreground` controls plain text color.